# Crear una tabla con una REST API HAL en Net Core 6 y Javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, api, asp.net-core, restful

Buenas tardes colegas,

Me encuentro trabajando con un sistema que obtinene datos desde un API HAL, ya consumo los datos y los muestro en una tabla sin problema, ahora el tema es la paginación ya que mis conocimientos en Javascript son muy reducidos por lo que acudo a ustedes. Les muestro el API HAL:

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "tasks": [
        {
            "deleted": false,
            "uniqueCode": "b870314d-3b34",
            "companyCode": "b6d8b23e-e696",
            "lastModifiedDate": "2022-09-19T16:54:02.787+00:00",
            "createdDate": "2022-09-19T16:54:02.787+00:00",
            "createdBy": "b425c4fb-2d47315d2938",
            "purchase": {
                "deleted": false,
                "uniqueCode": "3dd867b9-272b",
                "companyCode": "b6d8b23e-e696",
                "lastModifiedDate": "2022-09-19T16:54:18.863+00:00",
                "createdDate": "2022-09-19T16:41:33.362+00:00",
                "createdBy": "PROCESSOR",
                "company": {
                    "uniqueCode": "b6d8b23e-e696",
                    "name": "MINI",
                    "logoURL": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/ejemplo",
                    "governmentId": "MMMMM",
                    "hasChildren": false
                },
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "https://app.ejemplo.com/api/purchases/3dd867b9-272b"
                    },
                    "selectable-budgets": {
                        "href": "https://app.ejemplo.com/api/purchases/3dd867b9-272b/selectable-budgets"
                    },
                    "selectable-categories": {
                        "href": "https://app.ejemplo.com/api/purchases/3dd867b9-272b/selectable-categories"
                    },
                    "patch": {
                        "href": "https://app.ejemplo.com/api/purchases/3dd867b9-272b/version/5"
                    },
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "href": "https://app.ejemplo.com/api/files/ae491204-1300/thumbnail/bytes"
                    },
                    "purchase-files": {
                        "href": "https://app.ejemplo.com/api/purchases/3dd867b9-272b/files"
                    }
                }
            },
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "payer": {
                "links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "https://app.ejemplo.com/api/people/b425c4fb-3e61"
                    }
                },
                "deleted": false,
                "uniqueCode": "b425c4fb-3e61",
                "companyCode": "b6d8b23e-e696",
                "company": {
                    "uniqueCode": "b6d8b23e-e696",
                    "name": "MINI",
                    "logoURL": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/ejemplo/165f4.png",
                    "governmentId": "MMMMMMMMMM",
                    "hasChildren": false
                },
                "name": "NAME",
                "lastName": "LASTNAME",
                "email": "user@ejemplo.com",
                "cardOwner": false,
                "costCenter": {
                    "deleted": false,
                    "uniqueCode": "3a7f69cd-c6184",
                    "companyCode": "b6d8b23e-e696",
                    "lastModifiedDate": "2022-07-26T21:12:09.479Z",
                    "createdDate": "2022-07-26T21:12:09.479Z",
                    "createdBy": "4adabe2d-a5b5",
                    "company": {
                        "uniqueCode": "b6d8b23e-e696",
                        "name": "MINI",
                        "logoURL": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/ejemplo/d84538165f4.png",
                        "governmentId": "MMMMMMMM",
                        "hasChildren": false
                    },
                    "name": "NAME"
                },
                "active": true,
                "fullName": "FULLNAME",
                "companyCodes": [
                    "b6d8b23e-e696"
                ],
                "initials": "MM",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "https://app.ejemplo.com/api/people/b425c4fb-3e61"
                    }
                }
            },
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "https://app.ejemplo.com/api/ejemplo/b870314d-3b34"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"_links": {
    "first": {
        "href": "https://app.ejemplo.com/api/ejemplo/?status=ACTIVE&sort%5B0%5D.property=purchase.payment.lastModifiedDate&sort%5B0%5D.direction=DESC&status%5B%5D=ACTIVE&page=0&size=10&sort=purchase.payment.lastModifiedDate,desc"
    },
    "self": {
        "href": "https://app.ejemplo.com/api/ejemplo/?status=ACTIVE&sort%5B0%5D.property=purchase.payment.lastModifiedDate&sort%5B0%5D.direction=DESC&status%5B%5D=ACTIVE&page=0&size=10&sort=purchase.payment.lastModifiedDate,desc"
    },
    "next": {
        "href": "https://app.ejemplo.com/api/ejemplo/?status=ACTIVE&sort%5B0%5D.property=purchase.payment.lastModifiedDate&sort%5B0%5D.direction=DESC&status%5B%5D=ACTIVE&page=1&size=10&sort=purchase.payment.lastModifiedDate,desc"
    },
    "last": {
        "href": "https://app.ejemplo.com/api/ejemplo/?status=ACTIVE&sort%5B0%5D.property=purchase.payment.lastModifiedDate&sort%5B0%5D.direction=DESC&status%5B%5D=ACTIVE&page=90&size=10&sort=purchase.payment.lastModifiedDate,desc"
    }
},
"page": {
    "size": 10,
    "totalElements": 90,
    "totalPages": 9,
      "number": 0
    }
}
```

Este es el modelo:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace software.Models
{
    public class Tareas
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("_embedded")]
        public Embedded _embedded { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("_links")]
        public Links1 _links { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("page")]
        public Page Page { get; set; } = null!;
    }
    public class Embedded
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("tasks")]
        public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public class Task
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("deleted")]
        [DisplayName("Eliminado")]
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("uniqueCode")]
        [DisplayName("Codigo Unico")]
        public string UniqueCode { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("companyCode")]
        [DisplayName("Codigo de la emrpesa")]
        public string CompanyCode { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("lastModifiedDate")]
        [DisplayName("Ultima fecha de modificación")]
        public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("createdDate")]
        [DisplayName("Fecha subida a sistema")]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("createdBy")]
        [DisplayName("Creado por")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("ownership")]
        public Ownership Ownership { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("purchase")]
        public Purchase Purchase { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("status")]
        [DisplayName("Estatus")]
        public string Status { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("payer")]
        public Payer Payer { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("automaticProcessStatus")]
        public string AutomaticProcessStatus { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("_links")]
        public Links1 Links { get; set; } = null!;
    }
    public class Company
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("uniqueCode")]
        public string UniqueCode { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        [DisplayName("Empresa")]
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("governmentId")]
        public string GovernmentId { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("hasChildren")]
        public bool HasChildren { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("logoURL")]
        public string LogoURL { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public class CostCenter
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("deleted")]
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("uniqueCode")]
        public string UniqueCode { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("companyCode")]
        public string CompanyCode { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("lastModifiedDate")]
        public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("createdDate")]
        [DisplayName("Fecha transacción")]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("createdBy")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("company")]
        public Company Company { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public class Currency
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("code")]
        public string Code { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("minDecimalPlaces")]
        public int MinDecimalPlaces { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("maxDecimalPlaces")]
        public int MaxDecimalPlaces { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExpenseCategory
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("code")]
        public string Code { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public class First
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public class Last
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href { get; set; } = null!;
    }


    public class Next
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href { get; set; } = null!;
    }
    public class Page
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("size")]
        public int Size { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("totalElements")]
        public int TotalElements { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("totalPages")]
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("number")]
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

    public class Patch
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public class Payer
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("links")]
        public Links2 Links2 { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("deleted")]
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("uniqueCode")]
        public string UniqueCode { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("companyCode")]
        public string CompanyCode { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("company")]
        public Company Company { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("lastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("cardOwner")]
        public bool CardOwner { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("costCenter")]
        public CostCenter CostCenter { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("active")]
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("fullName")]
        public string FullName { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("companyCodes")]
        public List<string> CompanyCodes { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("initials")]
        public string Initials { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("_links")]
        public Links2 Links3 { get; set; } = null!;
    }
    
    public class Purchase
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("deleted")]
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("uniqueCode")]
        public string UniqueCode { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("companyCode")]
        public string CompanyCode { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("lastModifiedDate")]
        public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("createdDate")]
        [DisplayName("Fecha transacción")]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("createdBy")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("ownership")]
        public Ownership OwnershiP { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("company")]
        [DisplayName("Empresa")]
        public Company Company { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("source")]
        public string Source { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("description")]
        [DisplayName("Comercio")]
        public string Description { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("version")]
        public int Version { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("seller")]
        public Seller Seller { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("payment")]
        public Payment Payment { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("budgetCode")]
        public string BudgetCode { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("budgetName")]
        public string BudgetName { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("readyForBudgeting")]
        public bool ReadyForBudgeting { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("amount")]
        [DisplayName("Importe")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public float Amount { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("effectiveConfirmedAmount")]
        public double EffectiveConfirmedAmount { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("sign")]
        public int Sign { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("currency")]
        public Currency Currency { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("cancelled")]
        public bool Cancelled { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("summaryStatus")]
        public string SummaryStatus { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("expenseCategory")]
        public ExpenseCategory ExpenseCategory { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("costCenterCode")]
        public string CostCenterCode { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("costCenterName")]
        public string CostCenterName { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("reviewRequired")]
        public bool ReviewRequired { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("invoiceable")]
        public bool Invoiceable { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("adjustmentOrRefundParent")]
        public bool AdjustmentOrRefundParent { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("foreignPurchase")]
        public bool ForeignPurchase { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("signedAmount")]
        public double SignedAmount { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("shortId")]
        [DisplayName("Folio transacción")]
        public string ShortId { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("_links")]
        public Links2 Links4 { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("confirmedAmount")]
        public double? ConfirmedAmount { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("notes")]
        [DisplayName("Comentarios")]
        public string Notes { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("foreignAmount")]
        public double? ForeignAmount { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("confirmedForeignAmount")]
        public double? ConfirmedForeignAmount { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("effectiveConfirmedForeignAmount")]
        public double? EffectiveConfirmedForeignAmount { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("foreignCurrencyCode")]
        public string ForeignCurrencyCode { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("countryCode")]
        public string CountryCode { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("city")]
        public string City { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("signedForeignAmount")]
        public double? SignedForeignAmount { get; set; }
    }

    public class PurchaseFiles
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href { get; set; } = null!;
    }
    public class SelectableAccountTypes
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public class SelectableBudgets
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public class SelectableCategories
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public class SelectablePeople
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public class Self
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public class Seller
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("merchantCode")]
        public string MerchantCode { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("category")]
        [DisplayName("Categoría")]
        public string Category { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("categoryDescription")]
        public string CategoryDescription { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("categoryCode")]
        public string CategoryCode { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    }


    public class Validation
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public class OwnershiP
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("owner")]
        public string Owner { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("group")]
        public string Group { get; set; } = null!;

        [JsonPropertyName("ownerPermission")]
        public int OwnerPermission { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("groupPermission")]
        public int GroupPermission { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Este es el controlador:

```
using software.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace software.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class TareasActivasController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<TareasActivasController> _logger;

        public TareasActivasController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ILogger<TareasActivasController> logger)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        

        public async Task<IActionResult> Activas()
        {
            Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUserAsync() => _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            var user = GetCurrentUserAsync();
            string token = user.Result.Token;

            HttpClient clientHttp = new HttpClient();
            clientHttp.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            clientHttp.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            clientHttp.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://app.ejemplo.com/api/purchase/");
            var request = clientHttp.GetAsync("?page=0&text=&purchaseCode=&size=10&status=ACTIVE&automaticProcessStatuses=AUTOMATIC_CLOSED,AUTOMATIC_FAIL,AUTOMATIC_NO_PROCESSABLE,NONE&sort[0].property=CreatedDate&sort[0].direction=ASC&status[]=ACTIVE").Result;

            try
            {
                if (request.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var resultString = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    var TareasActivas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tareas>(resultString);

                    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, TareasActivas);
                }
                else
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Esta es mi vista:

```
@model Tareas
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Tareas Activas";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutIframe.cshtml";                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}
<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<!-- Main content -->
<div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <!-- /.card-header -->
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <table id="tareasActivas" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model._embedded.Tasks[0].Purchase.ShortId)
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model._embedded.Tasks[0].Purchase.CreatedDate)
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model._embedded.Tasks[0].CreatedDate)
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model._embedded.Tasks[0].Purchase.Seller.Category)
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model._embedded.Tasks[0].Purchase.Description)
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model._embedded.Tasks[0].Purchase.Amount)
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model._embedded.Tasks[0].Purchase.Company.Name)
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model._embedded.Tasks[0].Purchase.Payment.PayerFullName)
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model._embedded.Tasks[0].Purchase.Notes)
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var item in Model._embedded.Tasks)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Purchase.ShortId)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Purchase.CreatedDate)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDate)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Purchase.Seller.Category)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Purchase.Description)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Purchase.Amount)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Purchase.Company.Name)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Purchase.Payment.PayerFullName)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Purchase.Notes)
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.card -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
<!-- /.content -->
@section Scripts {
    <!-- DataTables  & Plugins -->
    <script src="~/Theme/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Theme/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Theme/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Theme/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Theme/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Theme/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Theme/plugins/jszip/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Theme/plugins/pdfmake/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Theme/plugins/pdfmake/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Theme/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Theme/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Theme/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>

    
    <script>
        function tableActive() {

            fetch("TareasActivas/Activas")
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject(response);
                })
                .then((data) => {

                    const Tasks = data._embedded
                    const page = data.page
                    const pageNumber = page.number
                    //console.log(pageNumber)

                    $(function () {
                        $("#tareasActivas").DataTable({
                            responsive: true,
                            lengthChange: false,
                            pagingType: 'full_numbers',
                            autoWidth: true,
                            language: {
                                "url": '/Theme/plugins/datatables/es-MX.json'
                            },
                            dom: 'Bfrtip',
                            buttons: [
                                'excel', 'pdf'
                            ]
                        }).buttons().container().appendTo('#tareasActivas_wrapper .col-md-12:eq(0)');
                    });

                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log("errorTable")

                })
        }


        $(document).ready(() => {

            tableActive()
        })
    </script>
}
```

Ahora si, en el API HAL yo recibo unarray que me contiene los datos de la paginación (Numero de la pagina, cantidad de elementos de la pagina, total de paginas y total de elementos en todas las paginas) de la misma forma me devuelve el array con los links de la "pagina siguiente", "pagina actual", "siguiente pagina" y "ultima pagina" pero en el Javascript no se como deberia o podria hacerlo en la paginación.

Tendran alguna sugerencia de como poder mostrar la paginación que me devuelve esta API HAL?

Aporvechando, estoy usando fetch y quisiera utilizarlos con un await de actualización cada 60 segundos sin refrescar mi pagina.  ¿Como podria implementarlo en esta configuración?

¡Muchas gracias colegas!